# Bounty on my question

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer, bounty

I have put a 50 point bounty on my question [How are the cyclones on other planets studied?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54119/how-are-the-cyclones-on-other-planets-studied) 2 days ago. There are 5 more days before the bounty expires. However, I have not yet received a good quality answer there. There is currently one answer with 2 downvotes. I cannot understand why everyone is getting so late to answer my question during the bounty period.

Comment: If I offer to pay the first person who neatly cuts my lawn ten euros, that doesn't mean anyone will agree to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, that’s sad for you but a bounty is not a garuantee that you get a good answer. Also there’s 5 days left